# Boolean logic in switch case statement - Java

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
 switch (i) {
     case ("+" || "/"):  
        setOperator("i");
        break;
 }
```

What is the best way to do this in Java?

Comment: I need to use a switch statement.

Comment: Why would you? This code looks terrible.

Comment: then use 2 cases if you really want another way

Comment: This is just an example.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Of course.

Just use

```
if(i.equals("+") || i.equals("/")) {
    setOperator("i");
}
```

OR if you have to use a switch statement, you can do it this way:

```
switch(i) {
    case "+":
    case "/":
        setOperator("i");
        break;
}
```

Basically, you can't really have multiple cases the way you had thought about it. It's not the same structure as an if statement, where you can do various logical operations. Java does **not** go through and do an if statement for each of the cases.

Instead, each time you have `case("foo")`, Java sees this as something called a Case Label. It is the reason that we sometimes opt to use switch statements, even though they are very primitive and sometimes not very convenient. Because we have case labels, the computer only has to do one evaluation, and it can jump to correct place and execute the right code.

Here is a quote from a website that may help you:

A switch statement, as it is most often used, has the form:

```
switch (expression) {
   case constant-1:
      statements-1
      break;
   case constant-2:
      statements-2
      break;
      .
      .   // (more cases)
      .
   case constant-N:
      statements-N
      break;
   default:  // optional default case
      statements-(N+1)
} // end of switch statement
```

This has exactly the same effect as the following multiway if statement, but the switch statement can be more efficient because the computer can evaluate one expression and jump directly to the correct case, whereas in the if statement, the computer must evaluate up to N expressions before it knows which set of statements to execute:

```
if (expression == constant-1) { // but use .equals for String!!
    statements-2
} 
else if (expression == constant-2) { 
    statements-3
} 
else
    .
    .
    .
else if (expression == constant-N) { 
    statements-N
} 
else {
    statements-(N+1)
}
```

Comment: Why did they give you a -1?

Comment: +1 This is indeed the correct answer. Whoever downvoted this please explain why.

Comment: @JackScotti it is good practise to mention in a comment, that you *fall through* the case without `break` (e.g. `// no break`). That way you know that you fall through on purpose and when you add more cases to the `switch`, it won't get messy :)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do as: `Fall through` in `swith case`

```
      switch (i) {
        case "+":
        case "/":
            setOperator(i);
            break;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (i) {
    case ("+"):
    case ("/"):
        setOperator("i");
        break;
    }
```